# How to filter an array formula in Excel

Tags: excel

How do you filter an array formula (that uses average) in Excel by using a flag in column `C`? I want to find the average value for all records that share the same ID and have a flag of `"Y"`. For example, in the below, column `D` would read:

[image: Link to excel table]

Answer (score 2):

In D2:

```
=(C2="Y")*(AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,A2,C:C,"Y"))
```

And copy down.

[image]